# Hierarchical data forecast using GTS

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchical-data, forecasting

I am running into an error when using GTS to specify two hierarchy groups.  The error is:

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = unlist(labels[levels])) :
>   length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

I've recreated the issue with the below code.  In this example, there are two hierarchies State/County and Industry/Sub-industry/product.  The State/County is constant in this example - this may or may not be true in my actual data set.

```
y3 <- ts(matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5,nrow=5))
blnames3 <- paste(rep("CA",5), # State
              rep("AL",5), # County
              rep("O",5), # Industry
              c("P","Q","Q","P","R"), # Sub-industry
              c("514","807","514","807","807"), # product
              sep="")
colnames(y3) <- blnames3
head(y3)

gy3 <- gts(y3, characters=list(c(2,2),c(1,1,3)))
fc3 <- forecast(gy3, h = 6, method = "comb", fmethod="ets")
```

If I use a different method such as bu, the forecast function returns successfully but any subsequent operations such as allts fails with the same error.

```
fc3 <- forecast(gy3, h = 6, method = "bu", fmethod="ets")
allts(fc3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used `gts` a few times, but don't claim to know everything about the package.  But hopefully this will help.

I think what is happening is that your `gts` object is specifying a hierarchy that doesn't exist in your data.  The first vector in your list is `c(2,2)` which would indicate that **State/County** is a hierarchy level.  However, all of the states and counties are the same in your data, so this isn't really a hierarchy.

Then your second hierarchy consists of `c(1,1,3)` but **Industry** is always constant, leaving you with just **Sub-Industry** and **Product** changing.

In summary, this does not look like a hierarchical series.  I noticed that the labels in `gy3` have many `NA`'s

```
gy3$labels
$G1
[1] "G1/CA"

$<NA>
[1] "G1/CAAL"

$<NA>
[1] "G1/O"

$<NA>
[1] "G1/OP" "G1/OQ" "G1/OR"

$<NA>
[1] "G1/OP514" "G1/OQ807" "G1/OQ514" "G1/OP807" "G1/OR807"

$<NA>
[1] "G1/CAO"

$<NA>
[1] "G1/CAOP" "G1/CAOQ" "G1/CAOR"

$<NA>
[1] "G1/CAOP514" "G1/CAOQ807" "G1/CAOQ514" "G1/CAOP807" "G1/CAOR807"

$<NA>
[1] "G1/CAALO"

$<NA>
[1] "G1/CAALOP" "G1/CAALOQ" "G1/CAALOR"
```

Tracing through the code, this seems to cause an issue with `aggts`

```
aggts(gy3)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = unlist(labels[levels])) : 
length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

`aggts` is called when you specify a `comb` method, which requires a hierarchical series.  `bu` does not fail, because it is bottoms-up, which does not require a hierarchy.

Long-story short, one way to correct your code would be to specify a vector of `c(6, 3)` encompassing the sub-industry in one group and product in the other.

```
gy3 <- gts(y3, characters=c(6, 3))
fc3 <- forecast(gy3, h = 6, method = "comb", fmethod="ets")  
fc3
Grouped Time Series 
4 Levels 
Number of groups at each level: 1 3 2 5 
Total number of series: 11 
Number of observations in each historical series: 5 
Number of forecasts per series: 6 
Top level series of forecasts: 
Time Series:
Start = 6 
End = 11 
Frequency = 1 
[1] -0.5835628 -0.5835628 -0.5835628 -0.5835628 -0.5835628 -0.5835628
```

This works too

```
fc3 <- forecast(gy3, h = 6, method = "bu", fmethod="ets")
allts(fc3)
Time Series:
Start = 6 
End = 11 
Frequency = 1 
        Total G1/CAALOP  G1/CAALOQ G1/CAALOR      G2/514     G2/807 CAALOP514  CAALOQ807  CAALOQ514  CAALOP807 CAALOR807
 6 -0.6227325 0.0344344 -0.8919916 0.2348247 -0.02331766 -0.5994149 0.2459208 -0.6227531 -0.2692384 -0.2114864 0.2348247
 7 -0.6227325 0.0344344 -0.8919916 0.2348247 -0.02331766 -0.5994149 0.2459208 -0.6227531 -0.2692384 -0.2114864 0.2348247
 8 -0.6227325 0.0344344 -0.8919916 0.2348247 -0.02331766 -0.5994149 0.2459208 -0.6227531 -0.2692384 -0.2114864 0.2348247
 9 -0.6227325 0.0344344 -0.8919916 0.2348247 -0.02331766 -0.5994149 0.2459208 -0.6227531 -0.2692384 -0.2114864 0.2348247
10 -0.6227325 0.0344344 -0.8919916 0.2348247 -0.02331766 -0.5994149 0.2459208 -0.6227531 -0.2692384 -0.2114864 0.2348247
11 -0.6227325 0.0344344 -0.8919916 0.2348247 -0.02331766 -0.5994149 0.2459208 -0.6227531 -0.2692384 -0.2114864 0.2348247
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.  For some reason I thought I read somewhere that the hierarchy values can be constant.  Turns out in my case I am grouping by a "customer" and then forecasting by customer based on the various hierarchies.  And for some customers the State/County hierarchy can be constant while for others it could contain different values.  Any suggestions on how I can make my code dynamic so that for those customers with more than one state, I pass in just the product hierarchy and for others I pass in both state and product hierarchies?

Comment: You are welcome.  Glad this helped.  One option may be to use `mapply` with two lists; one list for the customers and one for the `character` parameters for each customer.  Then within `mapply` call a custom function to create a `gts` object.  Not sure if that will work or not - but it's the first thought that comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

The `blnames3` in the example has been specified wrong. Only one state and one county has been given to the column names, which fails to form a hierarchy. You need to provide at least two states and two more counties to construct a grouped time series.

I gather you've seen [Rob's post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/gts/) on how to specify the `characters` argument in the `gts()` function. Now I add one more level named as **"Product"** into the Industry/Sub-industry hierarchy based on Rob's example.

The code below suggests that there are two states with two counties each, and two industries comprised of three and two sub-industries respectively. In addition, each sub-industry produces four products.

```
y3 <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300),ncol=60,nrow=5))
blnames3 <- paste0(rep(c("CA", "NY"), each = 30), # State
               rep(c("AL", "LA", "CL", "ES"), each = 15), # County
               rep(c("O", "O", "O", "C", "C"), 12), # Industry
               rep(c("p", "q", "r", "p", "q"), 12),  # Sub-industry
               rep(504:507, 15)) # Product
colnames(y3) <- blnames3

gy3 <- gts(y3, characters=list(c(2,2),c(1,1,3)))
fc3 <- forecast(gy3, h = 6, method = "comb", fmethod="ets")
aggts(fc3)
```

Hope it helps a bit.